# Product of projections and commutativity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $P_1$, $P_2$, $\dots$, $P_m\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be orthogonal projections projecting onto subspaces $V_1$, $V_2$, $\dots$, $V_m$, respectively, and let $P_{1\cap2\cap\dots\cap m}$ denote the projection onto the intersection subspace $V_1\cap V_2\cap\dots \cap V_m$.

Is it true that, if
\begin{equation}
P_1P_2\cdots P_m=P_{1\cap2\cap\dots\cap m},
\end{equation}
then $P_1$, $P_2$, $\dots$, $P_m$ commute $m$-wise, i.e. $P_1P_2\cdots P_m=P_{i_1}P_{i_2}\cdots P_{i_m}$ for every permutation $(i_1,i_2,\dots,i_m)$ of $(1,2,\dots,m)$? (Of course, if $m=2$ the result is trivially true, but what about the case $m>2$?)

Thank you very much for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take
$$
P_1 = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, \quad
P_2 = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&1}, \quad
P_3 = \frac12\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1}
$$
Then $P_1P_2P_3=0$. Moreover,
$$
V_1 = span\pmatrix{1\\0},
V_2= span\pmatrix{ 0\\1},
V_3 = span\pmatrix{1\\1},
$$
hence $V_1\cap V_2 \cap V_3=0$ and $P_{1\cap2\cap3}=0$.
But $P_1$ and $P_2$ do not commute with $P_3$, and $P_1P_3P_2\ne0=P_1P_2P_3$.